# Getting an xpath value of an node with out iterating in java

Tags: java, xpath

I have an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<information>
  <person id="1">
  <name>Deep</name>
  <age>34</age>
  <gender>Male</gender>
  </person>

 <person id="2">
  <name>Kumar</name>
  <age>24</age>
  <gender>Male</gender>
  </person>

  <person id="3">
  <name>Deepali</name>
  <age>19</age>
  <gender>Female</gender>
  </person>

  <!-- more persons... -->
</information>
```

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("persons.xml");
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//information/person[0]/name/text()");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        Node node = (Node) result;
        System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
```

And i need to extract the name of the first person i tried the above code it gives exception  can any one help me in this,

UPDATED 
Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.Node
    at xml.main(xml.java:33)
```

UPDATED ANSWER

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//information/person[1]/name");

        String str = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

        System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Ramesh, suppose I went to the doctor and said, "I feel sick, but I won't tell you my symptoms. Can you help me?"

Comment: Sorry for not providing the exception . I have updated the question please have a look

Comment: You updated your question with "UPDATED ANSWER". Does this mean your question has been answered, or do you still need help? The normal way to answer your own question would be to fill in a new answer at the bottom of the page, rather than edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

XPath indexing starts at base 1, not 0 as most would think, so person[0] won't return anything. 
Change your XPath to `//information/person[1]/name/text()`
You could also specify the position to avoid simply using static numbers altogether: `//information/person[position()=1]/name/text()`

or `//information/person[@id='1']/name/text()` if you need it by id.

Comment: [1] is just a shorthand for [position()=1]. It's not indexing as in "array index".

Comment: You're right, this is a node list, not an array, and position() is not the same as indexing inside an array. Good thing we're not using arrays ;)

Comment: @jdwilemo: I think Marko was responding to your statement "You could also specify the position to avoid indexing altogether". His point is that you're not avoiding anything... `[1]` and `[position() = 1]` are exactly equivalent.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I meant "indexing" as just using a static numeric value over the position function to specify the node location. I mainly wanted to show Ramesh and others who view this the different ways of retrieving a node, and since you can't apply operators for ranges without using position() ex:(person[1>=]), I wanted to show both person[1] and person[position()=1]

Answer (score 1):

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//information/person[1]/name");

```
    String str = (String) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);

    System.out.println(str);
```