# Node.getNodeValue() returns null in java

Tags: java, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to find the node value by evaluating the `xpath` expression.

```
String resp="<response><result><phone>1234</phone><sys_id>dfcgf34dfg56</sys_id></result></response>";

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document dDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(resp.getBytes("utf-8"))));


XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("//response/result/sys_id", dDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println(node.getNodeName()+" , "+node.getNodeValue());
```

This gives the output : `sys_id , null` when the sys_id is clearly not null.

The [xpath evaluator](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester) returns correct value.

Can anybody point out any error?

Thank you!

Comment: your code looks ok, but debugging it, `dDoc` is always null so `sys_id` will be null....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert in XPath, but based on [this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111360/getting-an-xpath-value-of-an-node-with-out-iterating-in-java) I was able to produce the following code which does work correctly:

```
String resp = "<response><result><phone>1234</phone><sys_id>dfcgf34dfg56</sys_id></result></response>";

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.dom.Document dDoc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(resp.getBytes("utf-8"))));

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//response/result/sys_id");  // these 2 lines
String str = (String) expr.evaluate(dDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);  // are different
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output:**

```
dfcgf34dfg56
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Regarding this, if the xml string consists of many <result> tags, how can we fetch the sys_id field of all records?

Comment: Try using this: `/response/result/sys_id/text()` ... This should return all the `sys_id` nodes, from which you can extract the contents.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your code: When parsing the input you use a variable called "resp" but you defined a vaiable called "resp1".

Dispite the typo: In order to catch the TextContent use **node.getTextContent()**

```
System.out.println(node +": " + node.getNodeName() + ", " + node.getTextContent());
```

The reason why your code returned null is: You are extracting an ELEMENT node and the result of getNodeValue() depends on the node type (see table in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)) and will always return **null** for ELEMENT nodes.

Comment: I saw this typo initially as well, but he corrected it so I thought the problem was something else.

Comment: yes, the problem is the call to getNodeValue() that always returns null for ELEMENT nodes